# Output Resistance Voltage Controlled current source

Tags: amplifier, analog

I am having problems evaluating the output impedance (\$R_{out}\$) of a voltage controlled volage source, the notes I am using say the output impedance is

$$ R_{out} = \frac{r_o}{1 +AK} $$

but I can't figure out how it was derived, can anyone help me with this?

[image]

Solving by Applying Test Voltage/Current:

$$ I_{test} = -\frac{V_{test} - Av_\epsilon}{r_o} $$
$$ r_o \cdot I_{test} = -V_{test} + Av_\epsilon $$

There seems no way of getting the expression \$\frac{V}{I}\$ because \$Av_\epsilon\$ does not depend on \$V_{test}\$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) You already have the (closed loop) open circuit output voltage as a function of the input voltage.

Place a short across the output and solve the short circuit output current as a function of the input voltage.

The ratio of these is the output resistance:

\$R_{out} = \dfrac{\frac{V_{O(oc)}}{V_i}}{\frac{I_{O(sc)}}{V_i}}\$

(2) Zero the input voltage, connect a unit test current source to the output and solve for the output voltage due to the test source.  This will give you the output resistance directly.

---

> Just released Ve should be zero, because Vi is zero, because we
>   haven't applied any input voltage to circuit.

For method (2), since the input voltage is zero, the output voltage is simply:

\$V_o = I_{test}R_{out}\$

But:

\$V_\epsilon = V_i - kV_o = -kV_o\$

By KVL:

\$V_o = I_{test}r_o + AV_\epsilon = I_{test}r_o - AkV_o \$

so:

\$V_o = I_{test} \dfrac{r_o}{1 + Ak} = I_{test} R_{out}  \$

Comment: Thank you, managed to solve my problem by following part(1) of your solution, don't really understand the procedure for (2) though.

Comment: You're welcome.  Have you thought through procedure (2) any more?  It's actually more straightforward than (1) since placing an actual short circuit on an actual output may not be desirable.  It's also easy to set up in a simulator to measure a circuit's input and output impedance.

Comment: I have thought about it but I couldn't do it.I have added what I have done to the question.

Comment: Are we supposed to assume the error voltage(Ve) at the input is zero? Because if we did that we would be able to express AVe in terms of Vtest and then get the required answer.Is that the right thing to do?

Comment: Just released Ve should be zero, because Vi is zero, because we haven't applied any input voltage to circuit.

Comment: @KillaKem, see my updated answer.